# Updating state in parent with Draft editor state?

Tags: reactjs, draftjs

I have a Draftjs editor in a form with other fields. The state for all those fields is being controlled in that parent component. How do I get the same behavior from the Draft editor as I do from the regular HTML form fields where it updates the parent state?

Regular input:

```
<input value={title} type="text" onChange={this.handleChange} name="title" placeholder="Title" id="title" />
```

Draft js editor:

```
<TextEditor placeholder="Write your summary..." value={summary} toolbar />
```

On change handler:

```
handleChange(event) {
  this.setState({[`${event.target.name}`]: event.target.value});
};
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can simply Do : 
In parent  : (not that I have add the `update={ this.update }` props)

```
…
render(){
    return (
    <input value={title} type="text" onChange={this.handleChange} name="title" placeholder="Title" id="title" update={ this.update }/>
    );
}

update(editorState){
  console.log('update',editorState);
}
…
```

In editor :

```
handleChange(event) {
  this.setState({[`${event.target.name}`]: event.target.value});
  this.props.update(this.state);
};
```

This will call the `update()` function of the parent, is that what you are searching for ?

Edit :

```
import React from 'react';
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom';
import {Editor, EditorState} from 'draft-js';

class Parent extends React.Component {
…
    render() {
      return (
        <div>
            <form>
            <MyEditor update={ this.update }>
            <form>
        </div>
      );
    }
   update(editorState) {
      console.log('editor s state', editorState);
   }
…
}
// from draft website :
class MyEditor extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {editorState: EditorState.createEmpty()};
    this.onChange = (editorState) => {
        this.setState({editorState});
        this.props.update(this.state);
    }
  }
  render() {
    return (
        <Editor editorState={this.state.editorState} onChange={this.onChange} />
    );
  }
}

ReactDOM.render(
  <Parent/>,
  document.getElementById('container')
);
```

Comment: I think this would be if I had the other inputs in the editor. I've got the editor in a form along with other inputs instead of other inputs inside the editor. I think I do see your point though that I can pass in a function that takes the editor state and will pass it up. That makes sense. Thank you!

Comment: Yes, passing a function to the child is the only "good" solution I see to update parent's state